# why getting first chace exception in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, exception

I made a sample to check what happen when Ctrl+C is pressed in windows console application:

```
bool    TerminationFlag=true;

int main()
{
    g_hTerminateEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    ::SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlHandler, TRUE);
    while(1)
    {
        if(TerminationFlag == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI ConsoleCtrlHandler(DWORD dwCtrlType)
{

    if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_C_EVENT ||
        dwCtrlType == CTRL_BREAK_EVENT ||
        dwCtrlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
    {
        TerminationFlag=false;
        ::SetEvent(g_hTerminateEvent);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I tested the code by running it using start debugging option in visual
studio when I press ctrl+c I get the following message

> First-chance exception at 0x7c87647d

when I press on continue option my code comes to the line `TerminationFlag=false;` even though I have handled Ctrl+C in control handler. Can you please tell me whats the problem?

Comment: When the first chance exception occurs, look at the exception record to see what is being raised and why.

Comment: @RaymondChen how to look at exception record sir?

Comment: The exception record is part of the `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` passed to the exception handler. Some debuggers have a special command to show the current exception record. (For example, windbg uses `.ecxr`.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you're using Microsoft Visual Studio from your description of the problem. The first chance exception being raised is the CTRL-C event which is trapped by the debugging environment. This is expected behaviour.

You can choose to ignore this: go to Debug menu/Exceptions/Win32 Exceptions and take out the CONTROL-C check from the "Thrown" column menu. This will ensure that the debugger only breaks on CONTROL-C when it is user-unhandled. See picture below:

[image]

Incidentally, you should be waiting for the termination event not polling for a flag. You may want something like:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
HANDLE g_hTerminateEvent;

BOOL WINAPI ConsoleCtrlHandler(DWORD dwCtrlType)
{

    if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_C_EVENT ||
        dwCtrlType == CTRL_BREAK_EVENT ||
        dwCtrlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
    {
        std::cout << "Terminating" << std::endl;
        SetEvent(g_hTerminateEvent);

        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
int main()
{
    g_hTerminateEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlHandler, TRUE);

    DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(g_hTerminateEvent, INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tryed what you said but still i am getting the exception"First-chance exception at 0x7c87647d in smallsample.exe: 0x40010005: Control-C." on pressinf ctrl+c

Comment: Hi Dany, check the picture included in the example - make sure you rebuild your executable after clearing flag 40001005 (Ctrl-C). Check your settings.

Comment: I think I understand the source of your confusion: CTRL-C is an interrupt and Visual Studio generates a  DBG_CONTROL_C in debug mode for convenience purposes. Ctrl-C is not an exception what is being reported is the DBG_CONTROL_C exception generated by debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

When running this sort of thing in the debugger you will never get the same picture as if you will run it without debugger. In debugger you typically cannot step over system functions that make console input/output. Debugger will unavoidable interact with system here.

The most reliable way to go on here is tracing.

This may not answer the question directly.

p.s. In your code samples as they are now there is no need for the event.

Update from MSDN:

```
Value   Meaning
 0 CTRL_C_EVENT
```

A CTRL+C signal was received, either from keyboard input or from a signal generated by the GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent function.

Comment: I would recommend you to put print statement into your handler that should print the value of the received parameter.

Comment: sir i am getting a value 0 in DWORD dwCtrlType when i pree ctrl+c

Comment: Recheck your code. As it is presented in the question, it should work.